# Should the wavemaker tag description be changed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am since long looking for wavemaker (a java/web based rad ide) sources, since they claim it is open source, without success. It seems this is no more open source software, they only give you a free edition but the only sources provided are not in sync with the current product (https://github.com/cloudjee/wavemaker) since the VMWare days.

I was pointed to SE by the link they put here http://www.wavemaker.com/developers/, and quickly found that the tag info also still describe it as being an open source tool, and that sources can be obtained (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wavemaker/info).

Of course I am a bit disappointed with the new owner, but I find also misleading that they can be described here, also, as being open, which is really not (or no more).

Should this SE tag, at least, be corrected or what? Thanks.

Comment: If you think the wiki info should be changed, then feel free to suggest an edit on [that page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wavemaker/info) by clicking the Edit Tag Info button.

Comment: @superbiasedman thx, I just did it (it's under peer review, though).